What am I missing with how I implement Google FCM for Azure in an Android Studio app?
Following the link to Azure from this post, I set up my Android Studio code in an attempt to have my app receive calls when the app is closed. However, I am having trouble with getting the push notifications registered. The Azure tutorial is not very clear about where to include the code, and I have tried putting it within the createAgent() function and at the end of the onCreate() function. I can get a device registration token retrieved, but nothing beyond that. In fact, based on the built-in messages I have in my code, it seems that the code is trying to register the push notifications and handle incoming call push notifications before the token is retrieved.
Here is the code I'm using:
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if (!task.isComplete()) {
                System.out.println("PushNotification getInstanceId failed");
                return;
            }
            deviceToken = task.getResult();
            System.out.println("PushNotification device registration token retrieved successfully");

            try {
                callAgent.registerPushNotification(deviceToken).get();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong while registering for Incoming Calls Push Notifications.");
            }

            try {
                PushNotificationInfo notification = PushNotificationInfo.fromMap(pushNotificationMessageDataFromFCM);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong while handling the Incoming Calls Push Notifications.");
            }
        }
    });

The first System.out.println is printed, but after the second and third are printed - which is why it seems that my code is trying to register and use the push notifications before the token is retrieved. I do not see anywhere that the code is calling the MyFirebaseMessage service. The only "reference" is the pushNotificationMessageDataFromFCM, but that seems to be using the result of the service, but if I put a breakpoint within the service's code, it is never hit.
Here is the code for the service:
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private java.util.Map<String, String> pushNotificationMessageDataFromFCM;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            System.out.println("PushNotification");
        }
        else {
            pushNotificationMessageDataFromFCM = remoteMessage.getData();
        }
    }
}

As I mentioned at the beginning, the Azure tutorial does not clearly indicate where the code needs to be placed, but it doesn't seem to work whether I put it within the onCreate() or the createAgent() function.

Are there parts that need to go in one place and parts in another?
Why does it seem like the FirebaseMessagingService is never utilized?
Why does it look like the code is attempting to do stuff with push notifications before the token is retrieved?
Any other thoughts?

Thanks.

Your code is not suppose to call your Firebase service, thats the job of google play services. From what I can tell that link is not complete as there is stuff in the manifest that should be there to register the service but is not mentioned in that link.
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService "
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

Please review the real firebase documentation for the full and correct setup

I apologize for not putting my manifest change - I do have that stuff in my manifest. As far as I can tell, I have done everything from the standpoint of what Google FCM needs and what Azure needs, but I'm still wondering why my code seems to jump to attempting to use the token before it acquires it.
